# why is the class property not getting initialised via typescript decorator

Tags: typescript

```
  interface ITodo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
    
    // propertyName : property decorated
    // target : the instance i.e object of class
    function GetToDo(target: Object, propertyName: string) {
      const getter = () => {
        console.log("getter");
        return [
          {
            userId: 1,
            id: 1,
            title: "task",
            completed: false
          }
        ];
      };
    
      Object.defineProperty(target, propertyName, {
        get: getter
      });
    
    }
    
    
    class TodoService {
      @GetToDo
      todos: ITodo[] = [];
    }
    
    const todoService = new TodoService();
    console.log(todoService.todos); // why not getting initialised by decorator
```

**todoService.todos** // **why is todos property not getting initialised by decorator**

code link : https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wing-dzf2g?file=/src/index.tsx

PS : i am new to typescript

Answer (score 0):

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

This error is coming from the code `todos: ITodo[] = [];` because of the assignment to the empty array.

What's happening is the object is constructed, the decorator function is running and creating its property, then the empty array initializer is executing. At the point where the empty array is assigned, the decorator has already created the readonly property, so it fails.

You can fix this by removing the `= []`. This will cause a type error, since TypeScript doesn't know that your decorator guarantees a value, but you can use a null assertion operator to override this (`@GetToDo todos!: ITodo[];`).

You can run a working example in [this TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUD2ATTyDeAUMsgK4DO0q2AXMiKQLYBG0A3McsLfU61BxJhgYADYQ65MFFABzQcgSZGAB3GQezTJnFwQHAL6FCAehPIVUTCuhgAngDk4jFHUvXbd5NghKocDVNzMDgoWQgwZDowAAsUUCk9JC4AOhRMZgArX0jMGEVROHJyQhhSEARhTBBkAHEIrAARTAAKELCIugB5LJyAGgsrGyh7JxdJaTkASgJOJRApZHCwSChkAF5kFpn1gD5ZkhJ58h0IFNFMWRaAImXV66mFEigI0igagG1OQ4Ofw4oqDwAIx9b5-bh0EFgn7CMQSZDXELkADW11Bf0OSlU6ggPHgoko6L+BiJJAAugoDBxOD1spUUj4YKAIAAFIaeNqhZYDdzDUbOCADIg-ZZ0O7QIkGR6EIyEBCFYrILC4ADK0AAbsBksLkAABepgJqYThgHCYcgAQjoGDNHwpMuMx0iptVGq1KE2IAgAHclWa1VBNUhthxjqdzpc2v63UgUi7zY9kGZkN6Yl4QJhInc5FwQCJgHBRMBKNhkMwvD4-AFMFBCEA).

```
interface ITodo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

// propertyName : property decorated
// target : the instance i.e object of class
function GetToDo(target: Object, propertyName: string) {
  const getter = () => {
    console.log("getter");
    return [
      {
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: "task",
        completed: false,
      },
    ];
  };

  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyName, {
    get: getter,
  });
}

class TodoService {
  @GetToDo
  todos!: ITodo[];
}

const todoService = new TodoService();
console.log(todoService.todos); // why not getting initialised by decorator
```

One quick warning - the actual object being created within your decorator isn't actually type checked as the value of the property (`ITodo[]`) (you could set it as anything, currently). I'd probably add some explicit type signatures there to help prevent accidentally breaking.